# Constructing a new array of specific field from an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a class that has an int and a string as follows:

```
public class Data {
    int _value;
    String _name;
}
```

and I have an ArrayList of these called list

```
ArrayList<Data> list;
```

Is there a way to construct an array of _values and another array of _names from the ArrayList?

Thank you!

Comment: Make some arrays of the correct size. Go through your list with a `for` loop. In the loop, set the elements in your arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just iterate through the arraylist and create two arrays by doing that.
something like :

```
int[] value = new int[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  value[i] = list.get(i).getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two new lists, one with the values and one with the names.

If you want to use arrays, you can use this snippet:

```
int[] values = new int[list.size()];
String[] names = new String[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    values[i] = list.get(i)._value;
    names[i] = list.get(i)._name;
}
```

But you can also use `ArrayList`s:

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    values.add(list.get(i)._value);
    names.add(list.get(i)._name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int valueArray[] = new int[list.size()];
String nameArray[] = new String[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){   
    valueArray[i] = list.get(i)._value; 
    nameArray[i] = list.get(i)._name;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more explaination than just a code snippet. This is not self explanatory.